# Pass widget name on button click

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can someone help, i need to generate 10 buttons and then when i click it must change the text on the unnamed button.

trying to get the event.widget but with no successes

```
from tkinter import ttk

root = ttk()

def gonow(e):
    e.config(text="clicked")

for x in range(0, 10):

     ttk.Button(root, name="but"+x,width="30", height=3, text=x).grid( column=0, 
     r.ow=0, padx=10, pady=5)        

     butok=ttk.Button(root, width="30", height=3, text=x, command=lambda var="but"+x: 
     gonow(var)).grid( column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=5)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

New update

```
                    b = tk.Button(frm_txt_json_case_btn, width="30", height=3, text=str(titulo+" "+cherep), fg=fcolor,relief=relifst, borderwidth=4,command=lambda titulo=titulo,wrd2srch=words2search,assumirrow=assumirrow,hiden_row=assumirrowr,resp_kib=resp_kiblog,repkib=repkib,urrrl=url_conf, jsump=jsonreq, explis=expectresq, frm_txt_json_case_tit=frm_txt_json_case_tit, inp_cond_protocol=inp_cond_protocol, resp_json=resp_json_input,lblexp=lblexpect, reqtxt=reqst_input,frm_txt_json_case_btn=frm_txt_json_case_btn: ChangConfWI(reqtxt, lblexp, frm_txt_json_case_tit, resp_json, inp_cond_protocol,urrrl, jsump, explis,frm_txt_json_case_btn,repkib,resp_kib,wrd2srch,hiden_row,assumirrow,titulo))
                    b.grid(column=colcount, row=rowcount, padx=10, pady=5)
                    buttonslst.append(b)

                    valbut=int(assumirrowr)-8
                    print(valbut)
                    print(buttonslst[valbut])
                    fvarbut=buttonslst[valbut]
                    print(fvarbut)

                    ttk.Button(frm_but_oknot, width="15", text="OK", image=photoOK, command=lambda assumirrow=assumirrow,filename=filename_report,exp=lblexpect,obs=resp_kiblog,urrrl=url_conf,tipo_de_conf=tipo_de_conf, resp_json_input=resp_json_input, reqst_input=reqst_input: savetoxls("geradorteste",resp_json_input,reqst_input, "OK",tipo_de_conf,urrrl,obs,exp,filename,assumirrow,fvarbut)).grid( column=0, row=0, padx=1, pady=15)
```

Comment: This code will not run, to begin with. And you are passing an integer onto the function and calling `config()`, ie, `int.config()`.

Comment: `x` is the index, not the actual button.

Comment: i know that, it was just an example, i dont know how to get the unique identifier of the widget and them call it with the config in order to change the text

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `x` to `gonow`, it is the index of the button, not the button itself. You could store the buttons in a list (note: the buttons, not the result of `grid`!), and then use the index:

```
buttons = []
for x in range(0, 3):
     b = tk.Button(root, width=30, height=3, text=x, command=lambda x=x: gonow(buttons[x]))
     b.grid(column=0, row=x, padx=10, pady=5)
     buttons.append(b)
```

Or postpone the command creation after the button is created and pass the button itself:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
     b = tk.Button(root, width=30, height=3, text=x)
     b.config(command=lambda b=b: gonow(b))
     b.grid(column=0, row=x, padx=10, pady=5)
```

(Note: There are a few more unrelated (syntax) errors throughout your code that you should fix.)

Comment: thanks,   tried that but it passes None  :S.  [None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: @frepynow What do you mean, "it passes None"? What passes none where? What is that list? The list of `buttons`? Then that's because you add the result of `grid` to the list, and not the button itself! If you do `b = Button(...).grid(...)` then `b` is _not_ the button but the result of `grid`.

Comment: gosh my bad :( thank you :). the problem is that its passing the name of the last button

Comment: @frepynow In that case you probably forgot to do `b=b` in the lambda, or left it as `x=x` but pass `b` to the function (search for `lambda in loop` for the backgrounds of that)

Comment: please the update to the post. the print work well but then then when i try it only passes the last one